# WPF combox new updating datagrid itemsource on new row

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, datagrid

So I'm really at my wits end here.  Doesn't seem like anything is working.   Should be an easy enough problem, but seems overly complicated.

New to WPF and trying to update the datagrid itemsource when I change a combobox and hit enter.   If there is a textbox or another field in the row, it'll save and update just fine.   However, some of the grids only have a combobox's.   I can modify existing rows just fine, but not new rows.   Seems like the combobox is not updating the item source when a new row is added.   Tried forcibly doing this on Selection Changed and on the Dg new row event, but I wasn't able to make it work.  I need some help.

WPF

```
<Window x:Class="ClinPath.Test"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ClinPath"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Test" Height="450" Width="800"
        xmlns:clinpath="clr-namespace:ClinPath">
    
    <Window.Resources>
        <clinpath:BindingProxy x:Key="CollectionList" Data="{Binding Path=collectionList}"/>
    </Window.Resources>

    <DataGrid 
                x:Name="dgCollection"
                ItemsSource="{Binding CollectionDetails}"
                AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="5"  Grid.ColumnSpan="4" 
                PreviewKeyDown="dgCollection_PreviewKeyDown" SelectionChanged="dgCollection_SelectionChanged"
                CanUserAddRows="True"
                >
        <DataGrid.Columns >

            <DataGridTextColumn 
                        Header="ID" 
                        Binding="{Binding ID ,Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"     
                        Width="*" Visibility="Visible"

                        />

            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Collection" Width="*" >
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate >
                    <DataTemplate>

                        <ComboBox 
                                    ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource ResourceKey=CollectionList}, Path=Data}" 
                                    SelectedValue="{Binding CollectionID,Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, BindsDirectlyToSource=True}"    

                                    SelectedValuePath="ID"  DisplayMemberPath="Details"                                
                                    />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>

        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Window>
```

CODE BEHIND

```
using ClinPath.StudyManagement.DataConnector;
using ClinPath.StudyManagement.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Input;


namespace ClinPath
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for Test.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class Test : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public Test()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            DataContext = this;


            //preload Lists and Combobox's
            SM_StudyDetail_DA da = new SM_StudyDetail_DA();
            ComboLists = da.GetStudyDetailLists();

            collectionList = ComboLists.CollectionList;

        }

        public int selectedProduct = 1;

        public SM_ComboLists_M ComboLists { get; }
        public List<comboObj> collectionList { get; set; }

        public ObservableCollection<SM_CollectionDetail_M> collectionDetails;
        public ObservableCollection<SM_CollectionDetail_M> CollectionDetails
        {
            get
            {
                return collectionDetails;
            }
            set
            {
                collectionDetails = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();

            }
        }

        #region Collection Data Grid

        private void CollectionEventUpdate()
        {
            SM_CollectionDetail_DA da = new SM_CollectionDetail_DA();
            CollectionDetails = da.GetCollectionList(selectedProduct);
            //await Task.Run(() =>
            //{

            //});
        }
        private void CollectionUpdate()
        {
            //await Task.Run(() =>
            //   {

            //   });                   
            SM_CollectionDetail_DA da = new SM_CollectionDetail_DA();
            da.Add_Update_CollectionList(CollectionDetails, selectedProduct);
        }

        private void dgCollection_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            DataGrid _dg = (DataGrid)sender;

            if (Key.Delete == e.Key)
            {
                int collectionID = ((SM_CollectionDetail_M)((DataGrid)sender).CurrentItem).ID;


                string message = String.Format("You are about to delete the following Collection!  \r\nCollection:{0}\r\nWould you like to continue?", collectionID);
                string caption = "Confirmation";
                MessageBoxButton buttons = MessageBoxButton.YesNo;
                MessageBoxImage icon = MessageBoxImage.Question;

                if (MessageBox.Show(message, caption, buttons, icon) == MessageBoxResult.Yes)
                {
                    SM_CollectionDetail_DA da = new SM_CollectionDetail_DA();
                    da.DeleteCollection(collectionID);
                    CollectionDetails.Remove(CollectionDetails.Where(x => x.ID == collectionID).FirstOrDefault());


                    e.Handled = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    // Cancel code here  
                }
                e.Handled = true;
            }

            if (Key.Enter == e.Key)
            {


                CollectionUpdate();
                //lblCalendarStatus.Text = "Changes Saved.";
                e.Handled = true;
            }
        }
        #endregion

        #region Property CHanged Events

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        internal void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string nameProp = "") =>
          PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameProp));
        #endregion
    }
}
```

DATA MODEL

```
namespace ClinPath.StudyManagement.Models
{
    public class SM_CollectionDetail_M
    {
        public int ID { get; set; } 
        public int SampleProductID { get; set; }
        public int? CollectionID { get;set; }

    }

    public class SM_ComboLists_M
    {
        public List<comboObj> CollectionList { get; set; }

    }

    public class comboObj
    {
        int _ID;
        string _details;

        public int ID
        {
            get { return _ID; }
            set { _ID = value; }
        }

        public string Details
        {
            get { return _details; }   // get method
            set { _details = value; }  // set method
        }

    }
}
```

BINDING PROXY CLASS

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;

namespace ClinPath
{
    public class BindingProxy : Freezable
    {
        #region Overrides of Freezable

        protected override Freezable CreateInstanceCore()
        {
            return new BindingProxy();
        }

        #endregion

        public object Data
        {
            get { return (object)GetValue(DataProperty); }
            set { SetValue(DataProperty, value); }
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Data.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty DataProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Data", typeof(object), typeof(BindingProxy), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is not the cleanest way.   I created a new method to add new row to database, updating both the database and item source.  Once the new row is created in the DB, it seems to allow me to set the value normally for the combobox.